# PostgreSQL Finding IDs that don't exist in two other tables

Tags: postgresql

I want to change the `io_dl` field from 1 to 0 in the `io` table, only if all three conditions hold true

`io` table pkey -> `io_id`

1. The pkey for `io` is not in the entire table `m` with the fkey named `m_id`
2. The pkey for `io` is not contained in table `p`, column `p_id` which is csv delimited string of ids ex. "1923,2309,210"
3. The current value for the `io_dl` field in the `io` table is set to 1

Step 3 I guess isn't needed as setting 0 to 0 doesn't really mess anything up, an extra check may slow the query down?

This is what I've tried and im getting a massive list of the same `io_id`s listed, I think I'm using join or union wrongly.

```
update io set io_dl = 0
where io_id in (
    select i.io_id from io i
        inner join (
            select p_id as "io_id" from p
            union
            select regexp_split_to_table(m.m_id, ',')::integer
            as id from m    
        ) q
        on i.io_id != q.io_id
    where i.io_dl = 1
);
```

Made my own solution a few minutes later with a simpler query i believe.

```
update io set io_dl = 0
where io_id in (
    select i.io_id from io i
    where i.io_id not in (
        select p_id as "io_id" from p
        union
        select regexp_split_to_table(m.m_id, ',')::integer as "io_id" from m
    ) and i.io_dl = 1
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `except` to get distinct `ids`:

```
update io
set io_dl = 0
where io_id in (
    select io_id from io
    except (
        select p_id from p
        union
        select regexp_split_to_table(m_id, ',')::integer from m
    )
) and io_dl = 1
returning *;
```

By adding `returning *` you can control how many rows were updated.